# Move IWebHost reference from program to controller .NET Core 2.1 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have this code that's working in my main program function and I want to move it to the controller.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var webHost = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
    var audioPlayer = (INodeServices)webHost.Services.GetService(typeof(INodeServices));
    var playBackResult = audioPlayer.InvokeExportAsync<string>("./play-audio","play","/Users/ryandines/Projects/SqlServerApp/dopeTrapBeat9.mp3").Result;
    webHost.Run();
}
```

So I implemented IWebHost interface, what is webHost called in technical terms?  I need to be able to access webHost from the controller.  If I try to change Main(), it complains about the signature, so I can't add parameters or change the return type in this case.  What is the most sane way to get this code over to the controller so I can use it in my views?

Edit:  Right now this code runs at startup.  Instead of my audioPlayer being instantiated here, I need it in my controller, but I don't know how I'd make a reference to webHost in order to get that done.

Edit 2:  Thanks Kirk, read the documentation, that was what I wanted to do.  I think I'm almost there.  It compiles, but no sound so I'm almost there.  I tried this

```
public IActionResult Index([FromServices] INodeServices nodeServices)
{ 
    var playbackResult = nodeServices.InvokeExportAsync<string>("./play-audio", "play", "/Users/ryandines/Projects/SqlServerApp/dopeTrapBeat9.mp3").Result;
    return View();
}
```

Edit 3 (thanks first contributor to post an answer):

This is from `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddNodeServices();
    ...
}
```

So background info, using this service that other people wrote here https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices to play sound.

Comment: it is unclear what you are trying to do and why.

Comment: are you trying to pass arguments to the main method?

Comment: I have this service that gets called with webHost and I need to be able to call it from a controller instead of here

Comment: Your question is somewhat difficult to understand - I *think* you might want to take `INodeServices` into your controller's constructor and then use that inside of your controller. You shouldn't need to be concerned about `IWebHost` here at all.

Comment: I figured out the last bug, I had to use the full file name once the code had moved to a different directory.

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to Kirk Larkin for explaining what I had to do and the fact that I didn't need IWebHost to get a reference to my service.  My final bug was related to the file path, had to call it by its explicit path instead of `./play-audio`.  Final code:

```
public IActionResult Index([FromServices] INodeServices nodeServices)
{ 
    var playbackResult = nodeServices.InvokeExportAsync<string>("/Users/ryandines/Projects/SqlServerApp/play-audio", "play", "/Users/ryandines/Projects/SqlServerApp/dopeTrapBeat9.mp3").Result;
    return View();
}
```

Thank you for explaining this to me.  Wish there was a way to give you more credit because you solved this for me.  Hopefully I don't get super down voted like every other time I answer my own question.